# operator precedence: not and comparisons

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand python better and the lack of parentheses can be a bit confusing for some reason.

how is `(not a < b < c)` evaluated?  Is it `(not a) < b < c`? or `not (a < b < c)`?

According to the [reference manual](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order), does `not` have a lower or higher precedence than `<` ? I'm assuming operators with higher precedence evaluate before those with lower, right?  I feel like I need someone to break out the sock puppets right now.

<s>According to the [Python 2.4 reference manual](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/summary.html) not and comparisons have a different precedence.  Then in the [Python 2.7 reference manual](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order) not and comparisons have the same precedence.</s>

If i'm not mistaken `not a < b < c` will have varying results depending on the version of python.  Would someone please share how this statement is evaluated?

I'm sticking with `not (a < b < c)`

Comment: add parenthesis where you need a specif evaluation order. People reading your code will be much happier to avoid checking documentation

Comment: There is more to understanding that code than operator precedence. Note `a < b < c` is not the same as `(a < b) and (a < c) and (b < c)` for two reasons -- you can overload comparisons so they aren't necessarily commutative, and that chained comparison is expanded to `(a < b) and (b < c)`; it implies nothing about `a` and `c`.

Comment: I find the `dis` and `ast` modules to be helpful with such questions, e.g. `dis.dis(lambda a,b,c: not a < b < c)` and `print(ast.dump(ast.parse('not a < b < c')))`. There's no arguing with the compiler.

Comment: @eryksun that only helps if you can comprehend the compiler... :)

Comment: agf, i didn't think about a<b<c being interpreted as f(a,b,c). eryksun, right! i haven't really used the dis module yet, very useful!  Thanks all

Answer (score 8):

What you're seeing in the 2.7 manual is all *relational* operators, including `not in` and `is not`, at the same precedence; boolean `not` is still one level lower in precedence and as such the relational comparison happens first.

Comment: +1.  To be clear, the "relational comparison" is `(a < b < c)` which happens first so the result is equivalent to `not (a < b < c)` in both cases - although @Jake makes a good point that it is often best to make it explicit with parentheses so there are no surprises if changing versions of python or porting to another language.